# How to execute thousands of commands in parallel using xargs?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I'm queuing up a bunch of jobs through qsub in a loop currently

```
for fn in $FNS; do
    queue_job $(options_a $fn) $(options_b $fn)
done
```

`queue_job` is a script that queues up jobs using qsub and options_a/b are functions I wrote that add a few job options based on filename.  I queue up to 5k jobs this way and I'd like to just add them all to the queue instantly (or in larger blocks such as 40/time) instead of in a loop.

I know I can send lines to `xargs` and execute them in parallel as

```
??? | xargs -P 40 -I{} command {}
```

but I'm not sure how to translate my for loop to `xargs`

Comment: Interesting. To help us visualize your problem better, edit your Q to include 4-5 lines of the what is in your queue job file (it is a file, right? (or could be substituted w a file for testing?)) Good luck.

Comment: just `xargs .. sh -c 'fn=$1; queue_job $(options_a $fn) $(options_b $fn)' --` ?

Comment: Which engine do you use (SGE ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qsub` interface allows for submitting one job at a time - it does not provide `bulk` submission, which will limit the upside of submitting jobs in parallel (job submission is usually fast).

For the specific case, there are two (bash) functions (namely, `options_a` and `options_b`), which will expand to job specific parameters, based on the filename. This may limit direct execution with xargs, as suggested by the comments - the functions are unlikely to be available in the path.

Options:

Create a wrapper for `queue_job` that will source (or include) the functions. Use the wrapper from xargs

```
xargs -P40 -I{} queue_job_x1 '{}'
```

```
queue_job_x1

#! /bin/bash
function options_a {
   ...
}

function option_b {
   ...
}

queue_job $(options_a $fn) $(options_b $fn)'
```

Might be a good idea to put relevant functions into `.sh` file, which can be sourced by multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is not needed.

If you background the task, the next task can be taken up immediately. You can add some intelligence to your script so that it caps itself on the number of simultaneous tasks. For example:

```
COUNT=1
LIMIT=40
for fn in $FNS; do
    queue_job $(options_a $fn) $(options_b $fn) &
    if [ $COUNT -lt $LIMIT ] ; then
        COUNT=$[COUNT+1]
        continue
    fi
    wait -n
done
wait
```

The `queue_job` command is placed in the background. The `if` body continues to spawn parallel `queue_job` tasks until `COUNT` reaches the `LIMIT`. If `COUNT` has reached `LIMIT`, then the loop waits for one of the running tasks to complete before spawning the next task. The trailing `wait` lets the script block until all the tasks have completed.

I tested this by simulating `queue_job` with a 2 second sleep, 30 tasks, and limiting to 10 parallel tasks. As expected, the simulation completed after about 6 seconds.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY07C8JAEIT7@xUrBhs35OEbsbIK@Gi0CikSc0cOwp6YEwvJbz8vG3Caj9kdZqqya5ybTqJKU1R5I47X@@V2SMQpO2eesVDmBYpAE3xjTDDtR@ACl7jCNW5wi7se9lAbAV5dK@UTUpix0wpyCLgUwtZCwL1Q@LxtJHFm0Dgb5Mx5UvwfD0NW01vyQWnGp9QWQhK1ISkG49wP)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
export -f options_a
export -f options_b

parallel -j40 'queue_job $(options_a {}) $(options_b {})' ::: $FNS
```